# How to mock the output of an instance method for an instance of the class under test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I'm testing an instance method of a class but it also relies on a call to another instance method. How can I mock the response from the second instance method?

Not the actual code, but equivalent:

```
public class A{
    public String[][][] m1(String[][][] arg1){
        ArrayList<String[]> arg2 = new ArrayList<>();
        String[][][] response = m2(arg1, arg2);

        if (response == null)
            return arg1;
        else
            return response;
    }

    public String[][][] m2(String[][][] arg1, ArrayList<String[]> arg2){
        return new String[][][]{{{}}};
    }
}
```

So here I would be testing method's m1 return values, but would like to mock the return of method m2

Comment: You can use a Mockito spy for that. Research "partial mocking" for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GhostCat mentioned, using Mockito Spies would be a good solution.

Ideally, you wouldn't have to mock an instance method to test another instance method in a class. If you're having to mock that instance method, perhaps it doesn't belong in the same class as the other instance method (take a look at this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430915/partial-mocks-are-bad-why-exactly)). If that is the case, you could pull that instance method out into its own class and then rely on an instance of that class (given to the constructor)--then you can just mock the class with that instance method when creating your class under test.

Or perhaps instead of isolating m1 and running a unit test against m1, it would be better to just run a test on the class that tests the entire class's behavior rather than just the behavior of the single instance method.

Alternatively, if the two instance method really belong together in the same class, and it is absolutely crucial that you unit test the methods in separation, and you're not using a mocking framework. You *could* create a subclass of class A that overrides m2 and returns a mock result for what m2 would typically return. Then you can test this subclass and successfully unit test m1.

**Edit**: If m2 is more or less a helper method that doesn't really need to be tested on its own, I would make it a private method and then not test it at all except indirectly through the public methods of the class.

Comment: Thank you, spies seem to be what I need. To continue I'm mocking the method in separation since in actuality the main method I'm using passes it's argument to the inner method, which then returns a modified object, but I passed a mock to the method that only returns the data required by the test if the response from this inner method is the same as I passed to it, that's why I'm mocking it. It's not to separate the testing for coverage or testing purposes, but rather a work around, it's not ideal, but as long as I apply TDD to both methods I think it's acceptable. Is there a better way to go?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean by this part: "I passed a mock to the method that only returns the data required by the test if the response from this inner method is the same as I passed to it". 
Could this inner method just be a private method, and in which case, I wouldn't even test it in isolation, since it is essentially just a helper method?

Comment: ya, it's effectively a private helper method. I mocked another elements instance method(not included in the example) that only returns the expected test data if it's passed the exact same argument as to the main method(m1). But I should still test the second method(m2) to see that it returns the expected value.

Comment: See edit I just added about not even testing helper methods except indirectly. Typically you don't test private methods because they don't contain (in most instances) the bulk of the application logic, they are simply helper methods that abstract pieces of code from the more important public method. Furthermore, the public methods are the ones that are actually exposed to the outside world, so by testing those you are ensuring that the private methods also work.
I would argue that you probably shouldn't test m2 since testing m1 should already cover it

Comment: yes, but then I should create a more elaborate Matcher for the mock that I pass to m1 as an argument. Plus this helper method encapsulates a significant part of the instance method's logic, the main method was getting quite large so I decided it would be better to separate part of the code, I can use reflection to test the private method even though that's a bit too much. But ya, I suppose that if the helper method is complex enough I just should mock it's response.

Comment: You breaking up the main method into separate methods is exactly my point--I fully support breaking it up, but I would still only test a public method rather than a private method. It's definitely a matter of opinion at this point however, so I digress.

Comment: right, but right now I need to choose between 1) mocking the response of the helper method and not testing it even though it's logic is complex enough to require it's on unit test coverage 2) or creating a complex Matcher that is passed to the main method, here introducing unnecessary time spending declaring the Matcher and it's own challenges. It would be best to just create a simple Matcher some how and pass it to the main method without mocking the helper methods response, but I don't see how that's possible. Just wondering if there is another approach that I'm missing.

Comment: I wouldn't do either 1 or 2--I would make m2 private, and solely test m1, hence indirectly testing m2. I realize this probably doesn't perfectly answer your question, but it is the approach I would take. I can't think of another approach right now either, sorry.